# Smooth Ring 3D in three.js

Tags: three.js

I want to draw a ring with the help of ExtrudeGeometry.

```
Ring3D = function(innerRadius, outerRadius, heigth, Segments) {

    var extrudeSettings = {
        amount: heigth,
        bevelEnabled: false,
        curveSegments: Segments
    };
    var arcShape = new THREE.Shape();
    arcShape.moveTo(outerRadius, 0);
    arcShape.absarc(0, 0, outerRadius, 0, Math.PI * 2, false);

    var holePath = new THREE.Path();
    holePath.moveTo(innerRadius, 0);
    holePath.absarc(0, 0, innerRadius, 0, Math.PI * 2, true);
    arcShape.holes.push(holePath);

    var geometry = new THREE.ExtrudeGeometry(arcShape, extrudeSettings);

    var material = new THREE.MeshPhongMaterial({
        color: 0x00ffff
    });

    var mesh = new THREE.Mesh(geometry, material);
    mesh.rotation.x = Math.PI / 2;
    mesh.position.y = heigth / 2;

    var object = new THREE.Object3D;
    object.add(mesh);

    return object;

}
```

The resulting figure has visible scars. And the cylinder and torus such scars not. How to get rid of them? Example [here](http://neftek.legko.ufanet.ru/MyWebGL/Ring3D/).

[image]

with `geometry.computeVertexNormals();`

[image]

Comment: did you figure out a solution?

Comment: No. Ii use TorusGeometry

Answer (score 0):

```
        var shape = new THREE.Shape();
        shape.moveTo(0, 0);
        shape.lineTo(0, 10);
        shape.quadraticCurveTo(35, 30, 0, 50);
        shape.lineTo(0, 60);
        shape.quadraticCurveTo(48, 30, 0, 0);           

        var extrudeSettings = {
            amount : 20,
            steps : 10,
            bevelEnabled: false,
            curveSegments: 8
        };

        var geometry = new THREE.ExtrudeGeometry( shape, extrudeSettings );
        var mesh = new THREE.Mesh( geometry, new THREE.MeshPhongMaterial( { color: '0x804000' ,transparent: true,opacity: 0.2} ) );
        scene.add( mesh );
```

Answer (score -1):

You need to `.computeVertexNormals()` from your geometry. But it seems there is some issue (with a solution) explained here: https://github.com/mrdoob/three.js/issues/323. I am not sure if it will work in your case.

Comment: Or your increase your number of Segments variable. It looks ok with 360 segments. Yes a lot more polygons.

Comment: 360? No... It also eats memory.

Answer (score -1):

I have found a comment in the code of ExtrudeGeometry:

```
this.computeFaceNormals();
// can't really use automatic vertex normals
// as then front and back sides get smoothed too
// should do separate smoothing just for sides
//this.computeVertexNormals();
```

So it seems it is not supported now :(